# Accidentally unplugged computer while running, now internet doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, internet

(writing this on my laptop).

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

I've tried rebooting both computer and router modem. I never had this problem until I accidentally unplugged my computer when it had chrome open and various other processes running. I don't know where to start with this. I haven't had this problem before. I can ping googles server 8.8.8.8 from cmdline and actually get a response but for some reason when I try to use chrome and other http requests it immediately (and I mean immediately, like it doesn't even try) says that the dns address cannot be found. I'm sorry I can't be more help. I can share dmesg.log and ifconfig if that would help (but I don't know what to look for there.

Also, everytime I restart I get these "system has detected problems" windows that pop up, but I just ignore those and it has not really been a problem.

It's also maybe worth noting that I recently ran into a problem where every time I boot I have to restart the lightdm service on a tty to get the X server running. Doesn't seem like it would have anything to do with it but it might be worth noting

**SOLVED**

> sudo dhclient

Comment: You mean you can ping google? Then the internet is working, only Chrome & web browsers are unable to connect? PS. Don't blindly ignore all "system problem" warnings, at least search for the exact message & see what it is, fixing them may fix this problem.

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes I can ping google, but it's not just from my browser (chrome), I also have some python scripts that sends http requests and it also is failing to connect. Also, I agree I shouldn't ignore it but since I was getting the same errors before I started having these internet problems, I don't think that should be the issue.

Comment: hmmm, maybe a firewall is stealing all the http port traffic, could be a router too. Or, if the startup errors were about filesystem errors then there could be errors in lots of random files, maybe it's just getting worse